# Webforms vs Contribution pages - workflow

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, workflow

On a clients site, we are using several contribution pages, and some of them are duplicated in webforms. I have a hard time deciding when to use what. I prefer the webforms, but I always end up configuring everything twice. What is the *intended* workflow ?

For a contribution, a contribution page is needed. But for a dozen similar contributions, I can use webforms pointing to the same contribution page, and configure the payment amounts there. However, since I can't 'hide' the civicrm page from the web, I do need to configure the amounts there, too. I always end up puzzling on how to sync these amounts from the contribution page to the webpage (pricesets - matrix - confusion).

On contribution pages, I can include 'profiles' to get additional information. On the webforms, I can just include the wanted fields from the contacts. since I can't 'hide' the civicrm page from the web, I would have to do both.

Comment: Tips on best practices are welcome, but they are not answers (otherwise, rogue mods will come along and ban this question for being subjective). The question is - what is the *intended* workflow here.

Answer (score 1):

Install the redirect module and make the contribution page URL redirect to the webform.

Comment: There are often multiple webforms related to a single contribution page..

Answer (score 1):

If your main issue is hiding the CiviCRM contibution page you could adapt the Drupal permissions (e.g. "make online contributions") in a way that visitors are not allowed to see or use them.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading this

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-Acceptingpaymentsthroughawebform

> When creating a contribution, event or membership webform that
>   includes payments, first set up a dedicated contribution page for the
>   sole purpose of embedding it on one or more webforms. Most of the
>   contribution page settings will be ignored by the webform. Only the
>   following need to be configured:
>
> - Title: This will be displayed on the webform
> - Financial type
> - Currency
> - Payment processor
> - Email receipt - if enabled, these will be sent from
>     the webform just as they would be from the real contribution page

So that seems to suggest to create a few generic contribution pages (membership,event registration,purchase), ignore the payments amounts, 'disable access' for those (using the suggestions from other answers here), and go wild on the webforms.

Comment: so it does not need setting to be a public form